# How to add New Widget in Added Widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

In the "PageLayout" I want to add a scrolling grid (I have a template "ScrollGrid()") and I do that using "add_grid" method. Now in every "ScrollGrid()" or in every page created, I want to add new widget "EventTemplate()". How can I do this?
This app is a kind of "To Do List", and every page will correspond to every day. It is correct to create a new page for every day, and in every page to add some stuff that I want to do in that certain day, or there is a simple method to do that?
Thanks a lot!
Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

class Page(BoxLayout):
    def add_grid(self):
        self.ids.page_id.add_widget(ScrollGrid())
    def swap_page_next(self):
        self.page = App.get_running_app().root.ids.page_id
        self.page.page = self.page.page + 1
    def swap_page_prev(self):
        self.page = App.get_running_app().root.ids.page_id
        self.page.page = self.page.page + -1
    def add_item(self):
        new_item = EventTemplate()
        App.get_running_app().root.ids.page_id ??????

class ScrollGrid(ScrollView):
    pass

class EventTemplate(BoxLayout):
    pass
class MyAppApp(App):
    pass

MyAppApp().run()
```

KV:

```
Page:
<Page>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,0.1
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button:
            text: "Prev"
            on_release: root.swap_page_prev()
        Button:
            text: "Next"
            on_release: root.swap_page_next()
    PageLayout:
        id: page_id
        border: 0
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            text: "Add Page"
            on_release: root.add_grid()
        Button:
            text: "Add element in page"
            on_release: root.add_item()

<ScrollGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
            size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
            size_hint_y: None

<EventTemplate>:
    size_hint_y: None
    spacing: 1
    CheckBox:
        size_hint: 0.1, 1
    Label:
        text: "Some Event"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from other answer as suggested by John Anderson, I'd like to add the following approach.

```py
    def add_item(self, page):
        new_item = EventTemplate()
        # Make sure page has widgets.
        if page.children:
            # Grab the current page index.
            index = page.page
            # Grab the ScrollView.
            scroll_grid = page.children[::-1][index]
            # Grab the only GridLayout of each ScrollView.
            container = scroll_grid.ids.grid
            # Now add the item.
            container.add_widget(new_item)
```

And in the `kvlang`,

```py
...
    PageLayout:
        id: page_id
        border: 0
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            text: "Add Page"
            on_release: root.add_grid()
        Button:
            text: "Add element in page"
            on_release: root.add_item(page_id) # Pass the PageLayout instance.

<ScrollGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 1
...
```

To show any page from any date (which has already been saved as a data in the disk perhaps) you just need to load a single instance creating from that data. Thereby you don't need to contain and load all the widgets simultaneously (which if really done could cause the application significantly slow).

Here you have to manage the page (or page-index) youself in order to avoid any error, that's why in this case I would rather suggest to use [`Carousel`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.carousel.html#module-kivy.uix.carousel) instead as there you will have more control.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the `"Add element in page"` `Button` out of the `<Page>` and into the `<ScrollGrid>`. So the `ScrollGrid` rule in the `kv` can be:

```
<ScrollGrid>:
    GridLayout:
        id: grid  # added id to allow easy access
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
            size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text: "Add element in page"
            size_hint_y: None
            on_release: root.add_item()
```

And the `ScrollGrid` class becomes:

```
class ScrollGrid(ScrollView):
    def add_item(self):
        new_item = EventTemplate()
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(new_item)
```